# Trying to define method similar to List<T>.ConvertAll(TOutput)

Tags: c#, linq

I want to define an extension method of `List<T>` called `MergeAll()`. I want it to take in elements from a list of one type and produce a list of another. I have a delegate defined for the `Merger` (equivalent of Converter)

```
public delegate TOutput Merger<in TInput, out TOutput>(TInput input)
```

but cannot for the life of me figure out the syntax of the extension method. My attempt is:

```
public static List<TOutput> MergeAll<TOutput>(this List<TOutput> output,
    Merger<TOutput, TInput> merger)
```

Then, what should the body of `MergeAll` look like?

Comment: What is the difference between you custom method and buil in `Select`?

Comment: You might start by looking at the Microsoft implementation: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,f4af030bcf8c8991, but not sure why your converter wouldn't just work with the built-in `ConvertAll` method?

Comment: What is the difference with `ConvertAll<>`, that returns a new `List<>` with the elements converted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're attempting is called a `projection`.

An extension method is already included in the .NET Framework to achieve this. `IEnumerable.Select`, and you can use it in the fashion below.

```
void Main()
{
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo> 
    { 
        new Foo { Name = "Fu" }, 
        new Foo { Name = "Foe" }, 
        new Foo { Name = "Thumb" } 
    };

    IEnumerable<Bar> bars = foos.Select(foo => new Bar
    {
        BarId = foo.Id,
        Name  = foo.Name
    });

}

public class Foo 
{
    public Foo() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar()
    {
        this.BarId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.TimeCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public string BarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Foo to Bar]

---

### How it's implemented....

If you wanted to implement a custom solution yourself for the sake of learning, this is how you would go about doing it:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TDestination> ConvertTo<TFrom, TDestination>(this IEnumerable<TFrom> fromCollection, Func<TFrom, TDestination> expression)
    {
        List<TDestination> destinationList = new List<TDestination>();
        foreach (var element in fromCollection)
        {
            destinationList.Add(expression.Invoke(element));
        }

        return destinationList;

    }
}

void Main()
{
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Name = "Fu" },
        new Foo { Name = "Foe" },
        new Foo { Name = "Thumb" }
    };

    IEnumerable<Bar> customBars = foos.ConvertTo(foo => new Bar
    {
        BarId = foo.Id,
        Name = foo.Name
    });

}
```

Comment: That's a good way of thinking about it. Thanks @Aydin Adn for all of the information in your post. The _subtlety_ of what I want to achieve is for each object of type A (in the IEnumerable being extended), I want to take some fields of object type B (passed as the function argument) to update some fields in type A. Hence my `MergeAll()`. This is a great help though.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `TInput` to `MergeAll<TInput, TOutput>` and to *change the first parameter* to be `List<TInput>` and the *second* to be `Func<TInput, TOutput>`.

```
public static List<TOutput> MergeAll<TInput, TOutput>(this List<TInput> inputs,
                                        Func<TInput, TOutput> merger)
{
    var outputs = new List<TOutput>();
    foreach (var input in inputs)
    {
        outputs.Add(merger(input));
    }
    return outputs;
}
```

A simple usage that convert `double` to `int` will look like below:

```
List<double> doubles = new List<double> { 1.3, 2.2, 3.5, 4.7 };
List<int> ints = doubles.MergeAll(doubleParam => Convert.ToInt32(doubleParam)).ToList();
```